# React 16.4 ComponentDidMount not respecting strict equality checks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**The issue**

Hello I'm running into a bit of a proplem using ComponentDidMount.
 I wish to perform a network request if the value is not undefined, it will be undefined when the component mounts, the value will be passed when a user is redirected by using the state that lives inside of `location` which I will passed to the component using`history.push(route, state);`
Consider the code below, I only posted the code in question since the other lines are irrelevant to the issue.
As you can see below I am making a network request if the data I'm performing an equality check on is not undefined, this indeed works when the user redirects because the value exists since the user performed an action which calls `history.push(route, state);` passing the route and the desired data to be passed, however if the user visits the component without first being redirected by using `history.push(route,state)` it will be undefined by default, in this case I'm checking to see if the value is defined or not, which should perform the equality check and not execute anything at all, instead the console throws me an error pointing to my logic for the issue, does ComponentDidMount respect equality checks for undefined properties?

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
    if (this.props.location.state.editData !== 'undefined') {
        const { asOfDate } = this.props;
        const { editData } = this.props.location.state;
        const { batchName, fileName } = editData;
        this.getFile(asOfDate, fileName, batchName );
    }
  }
```

this is the error I am getting

```
Cannot read property 'editData' of undefined
    at SingleTransactionContainer.componentDidMount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below condition

```
  if (this.props.location && this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.editData !== 'undefined') {
      const { asOfDate } = this.props;
    const { editData } = this.props.location.state;
    const { batchName, fileName } = editData;
    this.getFile(asOfDate, fileName, batchName );
 }
```

Comment: Sorry I didn’t get that

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access a key in an undefined object.

So you should assure that you can access the value of your key.

The best way to do it is:

```
(((this.props || {}).location || {}).state || {}).editData
```

which will return `undefined` if you are not receiving your props.

To resume, the problem is in your `if condition` and also `undefined` not `"undefined"` because if you compare

```
undefined === "undefined" --> false
```